# Can anyone help me simplify?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var GAME1NUM = "";
if (json.participantIdentities[0].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 0;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[1].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 1;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[2].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 2;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[3].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 3;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[4].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 4;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[5].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 5;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[6].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 6;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[7].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 7;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[8].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 8;
} else if (json.participantIdentities[9].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
  var GAME1NUM = 9;
}
```

need help simplifying the code it feels repetitive

really please help, its fine if you dont but if you can please man please

Comment: Does ACTUALNAME change between your ID statements?

Comment: In ES6 the entire code would just be `var GAME1NUM = json.participantIdentities.findIndex(item => item.player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME)`, assuming `json.participantIdentities` is an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) from ES6:

```
var GAME1NUM = json.participantIdentities.findIndex(function(val) {
    return val.player.summonerName === ACTUALNAME;
});
```

If you need more browser compatibility, use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill).

Comment: IE doesn't support findIndex

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Yep, that's what the polyfill is for. Nowadays people use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) though anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
var json = {
  name1 : "name1",
  name2 : "name2"
}

function getName(summonerName){
  return {
    name1 : 1,
    name2 : 2
  }[summonerName]
}

var GAME1NUM = getName(json.name1);
console.log(GAME1NUM);
```

You create a function that returns an object and you can get access the value of the property of the object with bracket notation.

The property that you want to inspect in the object is passed in as a parameter to the function.

If you use JSON. remember to do JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0):

**You can simplify your logic in this way :**

**Working demo :**

```js
var json = {
  participantIdentities: [
    {"player":{"summonerName":"ACTUALNAME"}},
    {"player":{"summonerName":"ACTUALNAME"}},
    {"player":{"summonerName":"ACTUALNAME"}},
    {"player":{"summonerName":"ACTUALNAME"}},
    {"player":{"summonerName":"ACTUALNAME"}}
  ]
};

var GAME1NUM = 0;
for (var i in json.participantIdentities) {
  if(json.participantIdentities[i].player.summonerName == 'ACTUALNAME') {
    GAME1NUM += 1;
  }
}
console.log(GAME1NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simplest way to implement that, without changing source array

```
var GAME1NUM = "";

for(var i=0;i<json.participantIdentities.length;i++) {
    if (json.participantIdentities[i].player.summonerName == ACTUALNAME) {
        GAME1NUM = i;
        break;
    }
}
```